# Can you programmatically determine if modern comments are enabled in Word?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, com-interop

Can you programmatically determine if modern comments are enabled in Word?

If it is not possible to check this directly [I don't think it is], is there any property of a comment that you can check that will indicate whether it was added or edited using modern comments? It would need to include comments that were originally added in the old style, but then edited using modern comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `Counts` property of the `Comments` collection:

```
ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
```

Use the [Comment.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.comment.range) property which returns a `Range` object that represents the contents of a comment. For example:

```
With ActiveDocument.Comments(1).Range 
 .Delete 
 .InsertBefore "new comment text" 
End With
```

See [Redesigned Word Comments VBA deprecation announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/word-comments-vba-deprecation/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works for both comments that were edited in the old style and comments edited with modern comments enabled, so I don't know if it can be used to distinguish between them.

Comment: Does the `Range` property exist for old style comments?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Comment: There are no other ways.